# Segmentation fault when accessing BST child nodes. Why?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

Segmentation faults occurring in function tdeleteLeft(x) when i try to access (x->left) in definition below:

```
void BST::tdeleteLeft(Node* x){
    if (x->left == NULL){
        tdelete(x);
        }
        else{
        Node* y;
        y = max(x->left);
        tdelete(x->left);
        x = y;}
}
```

And here is the full program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>  
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class BST {
    public:
    typedef struct node {
              int value;         
              struct node *left;  
              struct node *right; 

              node() {
                left = NULL;
                right = NULL;
                }
       }Node;

    Node *root;
    Node* i;
    Node* y;
    int z;
    static int c;


    int count();
    void inc();
    BST(int n);
    void tdelete(Node* x);
    Node* max(Node* x);
    void remove_node(Node* x);
    Node* min(Node* x);
    void tdeleteLeft(Node* x);
    void insert(Node* tree, int val);

};




int main ()
{  
  // create BST tree with n nodes
  BST *tree = new BST(10);

  clock_t t;
  t = clock();
  tree->remove_node(tree->root);
  t = clock() - t;
  cout << t << " clicks " <<  ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "seconds).\n" << endl;

  return 0;
}




BST::BST(int n){
    c = 1;
    z = 0;
    Node *root = NULL;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int rando = rand() % 10;
        insert(root, rando);
        }
    cout << "created " << n << "-node BST" << endl; 
}

int BST::c;

int BST::count(){
    return c;
    }

void BST::inc(){
    c++;
    }


BST::Node* BST::max(Node* x){
    if (x->right == NULL){
        return x;
        }
    else
        return max(x->right);   
    }

BST::Node* BST::min(Node* x){
    Node* i = x;
    while (i->left !=NULL){
        i = i->left;
        }
    return i    ;
    }


void BST::tdelete(Node* x){
    if (x->right!=NULL){
        tdelete(x->right);
        }
    if  (x->left!=NULL){
        tdelete(x->left);
        }
    delete(x);
    }

void BST::tdeleteLeft(Node* x){
    if (x->left == NULL){
        tdelete(x);
        }
        else{
        Node* y;
        y = max(x->left);
        tdelete(x->left);
        x = y;}
}

void BST::remove_node(Node* x){
    tdeleteLeft(x);
}



void BST::insert(Node *tree, int val){

               if(tree==NULL){
                    BST::Node* tree = new BST::Node();
                    tree->left = NULL;
                    tree->right = NULL;
                    tree->value = val;
                    c++;
                    }
               else{
                    if(c%2==0){
                        insert(tree->left, val);}
                    else
                    insert(tree->right, val);}

}
```

Comment: Apparently the function tdeleteLeft is called with x = NULL, add an if statement for that, add a breakpoint in the if statement and check the call stack to understand why this happens.

Comment: Then i think it must be a problem with my insert function when i call my BST constructor.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the following declaration of the local variable `root` in `BST::BST(int)`

```
BST::BST(int n){
    c = 1;
    z = 0;
    Node *root = NULL;  // <--- This defines a local variable which shadows BST::root
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    ...
```

[shadows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the member of the same name. Correspondingly, `tree->root` in `main` remains uninitialized after the call to the constructor.
As a result `tree->remove_node(tree->root)` attempt to delete the "left" node of an uninitialized pointer, which result in the segmentation fault you are observing. To resolve that problem, you need to remove the local declaration of the `root` variable:

```
BST::BST(int n){
    c = 1;
    z = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    ...
```

Then you should note that `insert(root, rando)` does not update the `root` variable in the caller context since the pointer is passed by value, so the allocated tree nodes become unreachable. To prevent this, you could either return the updated root node with:

```
Node* BST::insert(Node* tree, int val){

    if(tree==NULL){
        tree = new BST::Node(); // careful about shadowing the "tree" argument
        ...
    }
    else{
        if(c%2==0){
            tree->left  = insert(tree->left, val);
        }
        else{
            tree->right = insert(tree->right, val);
        }
    }
    return tree;
}
```

which you'd call in the constructor like so:

```
BST::BST(int n){
    c = 1;
    z = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int rando = rand() % 10;
        root = insert(root, rando);
    }
}
```

or pass the pointer by reference:

```
void BST::insert(Node*& tree, int val){
   ...
}
```